# How to Write Integration test to check whether throwing exception in JAVA using TestNG?

Tags: java, hibernate, testng, postgresql-9.1

I have a DAO which return some values and how to check a method throws an specific exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TestNG: How to test for mandatory exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677271/testng-how-to-test-for-mandatory-exceptions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using JUnit and you expect a test to throw a specific exception, do this:

```
@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public throwsExceptionWhenPassedAnIllegalValue() {
   [...]
}
```

If you're using TestNG, similar syntax:

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = MyException.class)
public void throwsExceptionWhenPassedAnIllegalValue() {
    [...]
}
```

If the exception that you're expecting is not thrown, these test methods will fail.