# How can I save an exception so it can be passed as an object to a function?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to unit test a function whose parameter is an exception. However, it seems that because the function only throws the exception and doesn't return in, I can't just feed a function and parameter that would throw an exception.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Hi, would you mind providing the code you're talking about, this will help us help you.

Comment: show the code please

Comment: JUnit4: `@Test(throws = ExpectedException.class)` and JUnit5: `assertThrows(...)` both seem to invalidate your "i can't do this" premise.

Comment: @Makoto - For completeness' sake can you link to a TestNG duplicate as well? That's the other major testing framework. This one should be an acceptable target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677271/testng-how-to-test-for-mandatory-exceptions

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas:  Yeah, alright.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a try-catch clause with the Exception you expect to be thrown, with a `pass` in the catch clause and a `fail()` after the catch clause.

Answer (score -1):

The major unit testing frameworks support verifying an exception.

Consider this method:

```
public boolean throwIfBlank(String input) {
    if(input == null || input.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input should not be blank.");
    }
    return true;
}
```

For JUnit 4, you could use the `expected` attribute of the `@Test` annotation to [verify that an exception is thrown](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/exception-testing). If the exception is *not* thrown, then the unit test will be failed.

```
// JUnit 4
@Test( expected = IllegalArgumentException.class )
public void testBlankStringThrowsException() {
  classUnderTest.throwIfBlank("");
  // test will automatically fail if exception is NOT thrown
}
```

Similarly, in JUnit 5 you can [explicitly assert that something is thrown using `assertThrows`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268446/junit-5-how-to-assert-an-exception-is-thrown):

```
@Test
void testBlankStringThrowsException() {
  assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> classUnderTest.throwIfBlank(""));
}
```

And finally, TestNG's `@Test` annotation [supports a variety of attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677271/testng-how-to-test-for-mandatory-exceptions) to verify that a particular exception is thrown:

```
@Test(
  expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class,
  expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "Input should not be blank."
)
public void testBlankStringThrowsException {
  classUnderTest.throwIfBlank("");
}
```

Of course, you can always wrap your test method in a `try-catch` block and explicitly call `fail()` if you do not throw the exception; generally this old-school method is not required but for completeness:

```
@Test
public void testBlankStringThrowsException() {
  try {
    classUnderTest.throwIfBlank("");
    fail("Blank string should have thrown an IllegalArgumentException!");
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // expected
  } catch (Exception e) {
    fail("Expected an IllegalArgumentException but threw: " + e);
  }
}
```