# Test System.out message printed in catch block

Tags: java, unit-testing, try-catch, testng, system.out

I would like to create a test case to test this `catch` block

I want to test this message `"File does't exit, please put the file inside resources folder."`
and `FileNotFoundException` exception using testNG.

```
try { //something here 

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { 
    System.out.println("File does't exit, please put the file inside resources folder.");
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: You may find some good ideas on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3677271/1081110), especially harunurhan's answer.

Comment: thank you Dawood, how about the body of the test case I already did the same but no good results

Comment: All you need to do in the body of your test case is run the method that throws the exception.  If you've set up the `@Test` annotation properly, with the right `expectedExceptions` and `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp` values, you don't need any other assertions.

Comment: I did the same but still fail 

@Test(expectedExceptions = FileNotFoundException.class)
 public void testCatchBlockInTask() {
  //method that throws the exception
          }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use `ex.getMessage()` and then use `testNG` `assertion` to verify.

Comment: @NandanA How will that test the System.out.println output?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think the question is not clear. He wants to do something like this    `Assert.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "File doesn't..");`

Comment: @NandanA There's no `e` being returned to any unit test

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Those suggestions will only work if the method under test actually throws, no?

Comment: Yes, @OneCricketeer, that's what Jack is trying to test.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code, you will get the FileNotFoundException, the file 'test.txt' should not be available in the path:

```
    @Test
    public void fileSetup() {    
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

            System.out.println(sc.next());
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("In catch block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with TestNG?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the question is, he wants to test the catch block  with the exception - 'FileNotFoundException'. What is it for you? why are you intefering with other's answers

Comment: The post literally says **using TestNG**. Plus, you didn't answer how to test (i.e. assert) the printed output using an assertion method.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, that can be answered by the questioner, you dont need to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Ideally, you don't use System output. You'd rather inject a logger and test against that.

But, it can still be done

```
// Store the original standard out before changing it.
private final PrintStream originalStdOut = System.out;
private ByteArrayOutputStream consoleContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTest() {
    // Redirect all System.out to consoleContent.
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(this.consoleContent));
}
```

You may need to do something similar for `System.err` for `ex.printStackTrace()` output...

Then run your function in a standard test, and assert against the `consoleContent` contents.

```
@Test
public void testFileExistence() {    
    doSomething("missing-file.txt");  // call a method of your service code that prints an exception
    
    int n = this.consoleContent.available();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
    this.consoleContent.read(bytes, 0, n);
    String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // TODO: split on line-breaks, and test printed content
}
```

After each test, you'll need to reset the stream, and if you still want to print the data, then do that too

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterTest() {
    // Put back the standard out.
    System.setOut(this.originalStdOut);
 
    // Print what has been captured.
    System.out.println(this.consoleContent.toString());
    System.out.println(String.format("              ====>Captured Console length=%d",
            this.consoleContent.toString().length()));
 
    // Clear the consoleContent.
    this.consoleContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
}
```

Or, more ideally, you define your own RuntimeException / Exception subclasses, then use assertThrows methods, where you can properly verify exception object content, including the message body.

Comment: This is not related to the question

Comment: Yes, it is. This is using TestNG framework, as compared to your answer, which does not